# How to Slide an Element In and Out of a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get better at JS and CSS, so I'm making a fake iPhone and am trying the simulate the look of when a text bubble pops on and off screen. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2NBQ.png) is what it looks like so far, and this is the HTML for the phone itself:

```
<div id="iPhone">
  <div id="screen"></div>
  <div id="me" class="bubble"></div>
   <div id="homeButton" class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

As well as the style sheet:

```
#iPhone {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 20px white; 
  border: solid 2px white;
}

#me  {
background-color: #1D62F0;
margin-top: 130%;
margin-left: 25%;


}

#me::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #1D62F0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em 0.5em;
}

#screen {
position: fixed;
   width: 241px;
   height: 370px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 0px;
   top: 8%;
   left: 1%;
   -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
   border: solid 2px black;

}
```

Right now, there's no JS governing it. How do I make it naturally slide onto the "screen" div and then disappear off the top, just like a real text message?

Thanks!

Comment: Just push thing beneath it and make it `overflow: hidden`

Comment: `#me` goes inside `#screen`, `#screen` has the css property `overflow: hidden` like @Bálint says. Then maybe use the `transform: translateY()` css property and a css transition to move the globe

Comment: Omg it's like magic :D thanks everyone! it totally works

Comment: @EML Lemme post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `overflow: hidden` property on the message container div, then simply push new message boxes beneath the already existing ones, so they disappear eventually.